# tsvファイルを分かち書きし、特定の品詞を基本形で出力したい

Tags: python, mecab, 自然言語処理

tsvファイルをmecabを用いて分かち書きを行い、名詞・形容詞・動詞のみを基本形でリスト化したいです。
tsvファイルを読み込み、mecabを用いて分かち書きし、ストップワードを除外するコード/名詞・形容詞・動詞のみを基本形で分かち書きするコードはそれぞれあるのですが、２つを組み合わせる方法が分かりません。
どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

**使用環境**
jupyternotebook
windows10

tsvファイルを読み込み、mecabを用いて分かち書きし、ストップワードを除外するコード

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument

import MeCab
import csv

mt = MeCab.Tagger()

reports = []
with open("reports.tsv",mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # reports.tsvには一行にID,文章がtab区切りで保存されている
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for report_id, report in reader:
        words = []
        node = mt.parseToNode(report)
        while node:
            if len(node.surface) > 0:
                words.append(node.surface)
            node = node.next
        stopword = ['では','のみ','か','まだ','はず','く','て','つつ','ば','でも']
        words2 = [token for token in words if token not in stopword]
        # wordsが文章の単語のリスト,tagsには文章IDを指定
        reports.append(TaggedDocument(words=words2, tags=[report_id]))
print(reports)
```

名詞・形容詞・動詞のみを基本形で分かち書きするコード

```
tokenizer = MeCab.Tagger()
tokenizer.parse("")
node = tokenizer.parseToNode("テキストデータ")
keywords = []
while node:
    if node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"名詞":
        keywords.append(node.surface)
    elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"形容詞":
        keywords.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
    elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"動詞":
        keywords.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
    node = node.next
print(keywords)
```

Comment: `['では','のみ','か','まだ','はず','く','て','つつ','ば','でも']`は名詞でも形容詞でも動詞でもないので、除外してもしなくても結果は変わらなそうですが

Comment: もともと大量にストップワード指定しており、コードが長くなってしまうため簡略化致しました。
たしかにこのコードが実装できれば不要になりますね！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最初のプログラム（tsvファイルを読み込み、mecabを用いて分かち書きし、ストップワードを除外するコード）の下記部分[品詞に関わらず、リスト化している（？）]

```
       while node:
        if len(node.surface) > 0:
            words.append(node.surface)
        node = node.next
```

に、二つ目のプログラムの下記部分[名詞、形容詞、動詞に限って、リスト化している（？）]

```
while node:
    if node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"名詞":
        keywords.append(node.surface)
    elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"形容詞":
        keywords.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
    elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"動詞":
        keywords.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
    node = node.next
```

を組み合わせて

```
       while node:
          if node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"名詞":
              words.append(node.surface)
          elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"形容詞":
              words.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
          elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"動詞":
              words.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
        node = node.next
```

とすれば、良いのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ストップワードを除外したいだけなら`node.surface not in stopword`の条件を付ければいいと思います。

```py
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument

import MeCab
import csv

mt = MeCab.Tagger()

with open("reports.tsv",mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # reports.tsvには一行にID,文章がtab区切りで保存されている
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    words = []
    stopword = ['では','のみ','か','まだ','はず','く','て','つつ','ば','でも']
    for report_id, report in reader:
        node = mt.parseToNode(report)
        while node:
            if len(node.surface) > 0 and node.surface not in stopword:
                if node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"名詞":
                    words.append(node.surface)
                elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"形容詞":
                    words.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
                elif node.feature.split(",")[0] == u"動詞":
                    words.append(node.feature.split(",")[6])
            node = node.next
    print(words)
```